# How to enable SSL for postgres connections for Heroku on Tableau Mac version?

Tags: postgresql, ssl, tableau-api

There is currently no way to enable SSL connections with a PostgreSQL connection on tableau's 8.2 version for Mac OSX. It used to be that you could create a generic ODBC and turn SSL as described here:
http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/howto/connect-to-postgresql-using-ssl-on-non-standard-port

Now there is no ODBC connections and PostgreSQL only has the following options:

[image: tableau connection details]

Has anyone solved for this problem with the Mac Tableau version with Heroku Postgres?

Comment: 1. the linked page is for Windows (note the reference to the "Start button"). 2. A postgres client with SSL support tries SSL first by default (that is, sslmode=prefer is the default)

Comment: It is giving a no SSL error, so it doesn't appear to be attempting to access it via SSL.

Comment: have you sent the same query to Tableau support?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a great long term answer, and doesn't answer your exact question, but might be a viable workaround if you haven't considered it:

You can use the Tableau data extract API to connect via SSL, read the info you need and create a Tableau extract. Then you can connect to the extract via a mac, and rerun your program on a schedule to refresh the extract periodically. You may even see a nice performance improvement, at the expense of not reading live up to the minute updates.

Then you can replace the extract connection with a live one, once Tableau improves their PostgreSQL driver to support SSL from macs.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I'm very dependent on the realtime reporting of tableau. I appreciate the clever work around for the mean time.